# Get pressed character in LWJGL (Ignoring modifier keys)

Tags: java, lwjgl, input, text, keyboard

I have a basic text field setup in LWJGL, however pressing any modifier keys (Shift, F1-19, Page Up, etc.) inputs a space into the text field. How would I ignore those characters? Here's some code so far.

Note: `value` is a string variable

```
while (Keyboard.next()) {
    if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState()) {
        if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_BACK) { //Backspace
            if (value.length() > 0) {
                value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
            }
        } else if (/* Character is not a modifier key*/) {
            value += Keyboard.getEventCharacter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried the if (Keyboard.event != Keyboard.LEFT_SHIFT, ...)?

Comment: @Bálint I tried that. Its really tedious, and it doesn't seem to work https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CaouSL4UYAEKoRb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, seems a bunch of RegEx works...

```
if (Pattern.matches("[A-Za-z0-9\\s_\\+\\-\\.,!@#\\$%\\^&\\*\\(\\);\\\\/\\|<>\"'\\[\\]\\?=]", String.valueOf(Keyboard.getEventCharacter()))) {
    value += Keyboard.getEventCharacter();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)`, and if it returns false, skip it.

Comment: What about punctuation...?

Comment: "||" os a great thing

Answer (score 0):

Add this where you add the code to the string:

```
value += String.valueOf(Keyboard.getEventCharacter()); 
value = value .replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\]","");
```